# How to prove $M(x)$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

$f $ is continuous in $[a, b]$. 
Show that $ M(x) = \sup\{f(y) : y ∈ [a, x]\}$ is continuous in $[a, b]$

I tried yo think in it as a constant function but this seems  not true

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

$M$ is indeed not a constant map. As $f$ is continuous on the compact $[a,x]$ it attains its maximum at a point $x_0 \in [a,x]$. Then separate the cases $x_0=x$ or not.

Answer (score 1):

Choose any $\epsilon > 0$.

We know there is a $\delta > 0$ such that for any $u,v \in [a,b]$ with $|u - v| \leq \delta$ then $|f(u) - f(v)| \leq \epsilon.$

Choose any $x,y \in [a,b]$ and with $|x - y| \leq \delta$ we will show $|M(x) - M(y)| \leq \epsilon$. This will show $M()$ is uniformly continuous and we are done.

If $x = y$ there is nothing to prove, otherwise wlog assume $x < y$.
Note that for any $t \in [x,y]$ we have $|t - x| \leq \delta$, in particular 
$|f(t) - f(x)| \leq \epsilon$.

This implies $f(t) \leq f(x) + \epsilon \leq M(x) + \epsilon$ for all $t \in [x,y]$.

Clearly $f(t) \leq  M(x) \leq M(x) + \epsilon$ for all $x \in [a,x]$.

Combining the above two observations we get

$f(t) \leq M(x) + \epsilon$ for all $t \in [a,y]$.

Taking supremums we have $M(x) \leq M(y) \leq M(x) + \epsilon$, 
i.e., $|M(y) - M(x)| \leq \epsilon$ and we are done.